# Getting the individual elements of an object c#

Tags: c#, object, oop

I am trying to look into an object and get the name of a person.
I have the class:

```
    string _name { get; set; }
    int _rank { get; set; }
    string _rankName { get; set; }

    public Class1(string name, int rank)
    {
        _name = name;
        _rank = rank;

    }
    public Class1(string name, string rankName)
    {
        _name = name;
        _rankName = rankName;

    }
```

and I have 50 objects in a stack and and popped it so there is a method like this:

```
    public Class1 getPerson() //this is in a Deck class
    {
        Class1 c = stackOne.Pop();
        return c;
    }
```

this what I tried:

```
Deck d = new Deck(); //this is in main
     Class1 person = d.getPerson();
     Console.WriteLine(person.name());
```

I've been looking but cannot find a solution to my problem

Comment: Why does the property begin with a `_` but your access does not?  Why are many of the names not compliant with standard C# naming practices? And why is the property not marked as `public`?  Why is the property accessed as though it were a method, not a property/field? All of these are very unusual for a C# program so I suspect that there is some deeper design problem here that you're not telling us about.

Comment: If some person, book or web site is teaching you that this is how you write a typical C# class, then odds are pretty good you need to get better learning materials because the ones you have are not serving you well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it with `person._name` which is a property name in this case.

Generally for property names it's better use identifier like this:

```
public string Name {get; set;}
```

Names starting from underscores are mostly used for private fields.